# Duplicate values from database when joining

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I want to get the tags and genres that are connected to the items using two relationtables, though I'm getting duplicate values.

This is my query, I'm grouping the values by the items id so I don't understand why it is giving me duplicate values.

```
SELECT
  name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(tag) AS tags,
  GROUP_CONCAT(genre) AS genres
FROM items
LEFT JOIN tagsItemsRelation ON
  tagsItemsRelation.itemId = items.id
LEFT JOIN tags ON
  tags.id = tagsItemsRelation.tagId
LEFT JOIN genresItemsRelation ON
  genresItemsRelation.itemId = items.id
LEFT JOIN genres ON
  genres.id = genresItemsRelation.genreId
GROUP BY items.id
```

[Here is a SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1923f/1)

As you can see it gives me duplicate values:

```
NAME    TAGS        GENRES
item1   tag2,tag1   genre1,genre1
```

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT(distinct tag), GROUP_CONCAT(distinct genre)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are aggregating along two different dimensions at the same time.  That is why you are getting duplicates.  So, if a name has tags, t1, t2, and t3 along with genres g1 and g2, then your joins are producing six rows for the name, with all combinations of the tags and genres.

If you have just a handful of multiple values for tags and genres, then the easiest solution is to use `distinct`:

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tag) AS tags, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT genre) AS genres
FROM items LEFT JOIN
     tagsItemsRelation
     ON tagsItemsRelation.itemId = items.id LEFT JOIN
     tags
     ON tags.id = tagsItemsRelation.tagId LEFT JOIN
     genresItemsRelation
     ON genresItemsRelation.itemId = items.id LEFT JOIN
     genres
     ON genres.id = genresItemsRelation.genreId
GROUP BY items.name;
```

If you have lots of duplicates (dozens or hundreds per name), then the generation and handling of the duplicates can be a real performance issue.  In that case, you would want to pre-aggregate the values along each dimension and then do the join.

Note that I changed the `group by` condition to be on `name` rather than `id`.  It is good form for the `group by` columns to match the `select` columns.